# Error with Add-ons Installation_Simply Cloth

Tags: add-on, installation

The Installation for Add-on **Simply-Cloth Pro** is somehow problematic. It shows the Error: register-Class(...): already registered as a subclass ´SelecVertexGroup´.

Does somebody know how can i solve the problem?
THX![image]

Comment: I assume since there is a pro version, there is also a regular version. Have you uninstalled, removed it from the addon preferences, quit and reloaded blender before installing the pro version ?

Comment: not yet! but it maybe very helpful! i try it now!

Comment: @Gorgious it does not work.... i have no idea, how could the problem be???

Comment: It launches that error in all versions but 2.9 it seems. Working on my 2.93 . I installed it manually extracting the zip and drgging it to the addons folder and worked so far.